# 'potential' {noun} vs 'potentiality'

Tags: difference

What are the similarities and differences? [OED on '-ity, suffix'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100360)  doesn't explain.
OED's definitions for [potential](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148805?redirectedFrom=potential) and [potentiality](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148806?redirectedFrom=potentiality) look identical (and are too long to replicate here).

Footnote: I encountered **potentiality** while reading [The Four Causes](http://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/320/4causes.htm) by Prof [S. Marc Cohen](http://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/currvit.htm) PhD in Philosophy (Cornell), about which I question [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/23034/8572).    I don't quote the context because I wish to ask this question in general.

Answer (score 1):

First off: "potential" can be either an adjective or a noun. For example:

- ADJ: Ms. Brown, a well-known judge, is a potential candidate in the upcoming election.
- NOUN: Ms. Brown, a well-known judge, will be a candidate in the upcoming election. I think she has great potential. [This is an example of potential meaning 'capacity for greatness' or 'promise']
- NOUN: Ms. Brown is concerned about the potential for violence in youth sporting leagues. [This is an example of potential meaning 'a thing that is possible' or 'a thing that could develop']

Potentiality, on the other hand, only exists as a noun. It generally has the second of the two meanings I listed above for potential.

Potential is far far more common than potentiality, and thus for practical purposes it's not important to master the correct usage of potentiality. Being able to recognize it is more than enough. Because it's a word that will sound unnatural in many situations, you risk sounding bombastic unless you are very sure of proper contextual usage.

Potentiality can be appropriate in certain situations where you want an additional level of abstraction or a certain tone:

- I believe that the elimination of world hunger is very possible; due to greed, however, it remains a mere potentiality.

Comment: +1 for bombastic (and "additional level of abstraction")